# How do I get my Rails 5 log to show me as many details about each operation like Rails 4 did?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

For some reason, even in development, my Rails 5 log only shows me some information.

I am not sure how it chooses what to show.

I don't know if it is because I have Turbolinks installed, but I doubt it.

Was there a change in the way Rails logs requests in development in Rails 5 over 4?

**Edit 1**

This is hard to show fully here, but here is an example.

I restarted my server, then I visited my `root_path` which is `questions#index`. Then I went to an individual question `question#show`, then I refreshed that show page. This is what the log shows of those 3 requests:

```
$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.rc1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-05-16 16:08:03 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by QuestionsController#index as HTML
  Rendering questions/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered shared/_main_page_heading.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Question Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions"
  User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (1521, 1522, 1523, 1524, 1525, 1526, 1527, 1528, 1529, 1530, 1531, 1532, 1533, 1534, 1535, 1536, 1537, 1538)
   (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 4]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 4]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (443.5ms)
   (1.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 5]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 5]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (5.2ms)
   (1.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 6]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 6]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (4.9ms)
   (1.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 7]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 7]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (5.0ms)
   (1.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 8]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 8]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (5.2ms)
   (1.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 9]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 9]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (5.0ms)
   (1.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 10]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 10]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (5.4ms)
   (2.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 11]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 11]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (5.7ms)
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 12]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 12]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (3.2ms)
   (1.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 13]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 13]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (5.0ms)
   (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 14]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 14]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (4.8ms)
   (1.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 15]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 15]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (4.9ms)
   (2.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 16]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 16]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (7.4ms)
   (2.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 17]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 17]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (6.6ms)
   (2.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 18]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 18]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (6.3ms)
   (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 19]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 19]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (3.9ms)
   (1.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 20]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 20]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (6.1ms)
   (1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 21]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 21]]
  Rendered questions/_question.html.erb (3.6ms)
  Rendered questions/index.html.erb within layouts/application (621.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1917ms (Views: 1844.9ms | ActiveRecord: 52.9ms)
```

It only shows me the first operation, not the 2nd 2.

Say I stop the server, while still on `/questions/4`, then restart it and refresh and then go back to the home page, this is what the log shows:

```
$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.rc1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/questions/4" for ::1 at 2016-05-16 16:10:55 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by QuestionsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}
  Question Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering questions/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1521], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (2.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 4]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 4]]
  Answer Load (2.8ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 4]]
  User Load (3.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered answers/_form.html.erb (535.9ms)
  Rendered questions/show.html.erb within layouts/application (637.2ms)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (1.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2666ms (Views: 2575.6ms | ActiveRecord: 34.4ms)
```

It doesn't show the 2nd request, just the first. It could be because it is being cached or maybe Turbolinks is serving up the last version of the page from my cache or something, but the point is that I am not seeing the request hit my server at all.

Not sure how to get all 2 or 3 requests to show up in my log. It is hard to show something not showing up, but I hope this explains it a bit better.

Comment: Can you give an example of an information you are missing in Rails 5 logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having the same problem using rails 5 rc1 and puma 3.4.0 I figured out the problem has to do with `quiet_assets` gem [having thread-safe issues](https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets/issues/47).
So your options are:

- Set an env variable `RAILS_MAX_THREADS=1` to run just one thread locally.
- Or delete `quiet_assets` from your `Gemfile` and have a messy log until [quiet assets be finally implemented to rails 5](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/338).

**UPDATE**

`sprockets-rails` has finally added the [`config.assets.quiet`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/355) option. So the final solution is to update `sprockets-rails` (and rails 5 also as there is finally a stable version) and add:

```
#config/environments/development.rb
config.assets.quiet = true
```

Comment: Dude...you are very right! Deleting `quiet_assets` from my `Gemfile` fixed it for me. The log file is hella messy, now I see why they preferred to quieten it. But I prefer it like this where I can see every request.

Answer (score 0):

You can control it by setting the appropriate log level in your config/environments/.rb file, e.g.:

config.log_level = :debug

Comment: I just tried that and it hasn't helped. I have updated the question with more details about what I am not seeing.